# How to block all .html pages in robot.txt?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt

I have a new website that has a different product URL from the old website.

**URL Old Website**

- `https://www.example.com/product/MA-593838554.html`
- `https://www.example.com/product/MR-559927541.html`
- etc

Old indexed urls with `.html` extension still appears in google search. How to block all urls whose extension is `.html` in `robot.txt`?

Can I write it like this `Disallow: /product/*.html$`?

Comment: Officially google and bing both supports `$` and `*` as regex in robot.txt, ideally something like what you suggested would work

Answer (score 1):

If you use the disallow directive in your robots.txt file, then Googlebot  access to all html pages in the / product / folder will be restricted. Instead you can:

1. **redirect** old page to a new page with 301-redirect CMS plugin or [**.htaccess rule**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) (if your website of the same host):

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   Redirect 301 /product/MA-593838554.html /product/MR-559927541.html
   ```

**or**

2. specify the [**canonical tag**](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls) from the old page to the new one in the `<head>section</head>` of each page. For example, for a page `https://www.example.com/product/MA-593838554.html`:

   `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/product/MR-559927541.html"/>`

Comment: can you give me a sample code of the 2 ways you told to me?

Comment: Your `Redirect` rule doesn't look right to me.  First the page to be redirected and the target **are exactly the same**.   The page to redirect should have only the path and the page to redirect to can have only the path on new version of Apache.  I'd expect something more like `Redirect 301 /product/MA-593838554.html /product/MA-593838554`

Comment: The new URL may be either an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and hostname, or a URL-path beginning with a slash. I'm edited my answer.